# Do dispensers decrease the recharge time of throwables (like Jarate, Mad Milk, etc.)?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-engineer

For some projectiles, like the Flying Guillotine, or the Shortstop's Ball, etc., upon use these items will "recharge", with a bar indicator in the lower right hand corner of the hud.

What I've noticed however, is that sometimes, when I'm near a dispenser, the speed in which the bar fills up goes slightly faster than normal.

Items that have "recharge":

- Spycicle
- Shortstop (Ball)
- Flying Guillotine
- Chargin' Targe
- Splendid Screen
- Mad Milk
- Crit-a-Cola
- Bonk! Atomic Punch
- Jarate
- Mad Milk
- Dead Ringer
- Invisibility Watch

Does the dispenser actually decrease the recharge time?

Comment: Hmm, I know going to a supply locker recharges these items but I have no idea if this carries over to dispensers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dispensers will only recharge a weapon faster if that weapon uses "regular" ammo - that is, if the weapon recharges by picking up ammo packs, dropped weapons, or building pieces. The Invis Watch and Dead Ringer use regular ammo; a level 3 Dispenser will actually fill your cloak faster than it depletes. The rest of the items on your list do not use regular ammo, and Dispensers will not help them recharge faster.